# Upgrading Magento 2.1.7 to 2.1.14

Tags: magento-2.1.7

Last year I migrated from 1.7 to 2.1.7. I used

```
$ composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition .
```

to create the Magento installation which I believe it is called the metapackage installation method.

Now I encounter difficulties to upgrade 2.1.7 and I already tried the standard procedure with composer to upgrade which should be possible, but I cannot see what's going wrong. I cannot upgrade with the Web setup upgrade because the notification says it is a git clone also.

Doing the following

`$ composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.14 --no-update`

`$ composer update`

gives me errors about dependencies of Magento itself (not other custom modules). My composer.json file looks very standard and it is quite similair as on [github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/magento/magento2/2.1.7/composer.json)

Here is a part of my composer.json file.

```
    {
        "name": "magento/magento2ce",
        "description": "Magento 2 (Community Edition)",
        "type": "project",
        "version": "2.1.7",
        "license": [
            "OSL-3.0",
            "AFL-3.0"
        ],
        "require": {
            "php": "~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6",
            "zendframework/zend-stdlib": "~2.4.6",
            "zendframework/zend-code": "~2.4.6",
            "zendframework/zend-server": "~2.4.6",
            "zendframework/zend-soap": "~2.4.6",
            "zendframework/zend-uri": "~2.4.6",
            "zendframework/zend-validator": "~2.4.6",
            "zendframework/zend-crypt": "~2.4.6",
            "zendframework/zend-console": "~2.4.6",
            "zendframework/zend-modulemanager": "~2.4.6",
            "zendframework/zend-mvc": "~2.4.6",
            "zendframework/zend-text": "~2.4.6",
            "zendframework/zend-i18n": "~2.4.6",
            "zendframework/zend-eventmanager": "~2.4.6",
            "zendframework/zend-view": "~2.4.6",
            "zendframework/zend-servicemanager": "~2.4.6",
            "zendframework/zend-json": "~2.4.6",

 ...
        },
        "require-dev": {
            "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.0",
            "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "1.5.3",
            "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
            "pdepend/pdepend": "2.4.0",
            "fabpot/php-cs-fixer": "~1.2",
            "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.3 <=0.7.0",
            "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.0"
        },
        "replace": {
            "magento/module-marketplace": "100.1.2",
            "magento/module-admin-notification": "100.1.2",
            "magento/module-advanced-pricing-import-export": "100.1.2",
            "magento/module-authorization": "100.1.2",
            "magento/module-authorizenet": "100.1.5",
            "magento/module-backend": "100.1.3",
            "magento/module-backup": "100.1.2",
            "magento/module-braintree": "100.1.6",
            "magento/module-bundle": "100.1.3",
            "magento/module-bundle-import-export": "100.1.3",
            "magento/module-cache-invalidate": "100.1.3",
            "magento/module-captcha": "100.1.3",
            "magento/module-catalog": "101.0.7",
            "magento/module-catalog-import-export": "100.1.4",
            "magento/module-catalog-inventory": "100.1.5",
            "magento/module-catalog-rule": "100.1.4",
            "magento/module-catalog-rule-configurable": "100.1.3", 

...
```

Trying to just copy the composer.json 2.1.18 file won't update the core files, right? What am I doing wrong that it won't work with the normal composer update? Do I just have to download the 2.1.14 archive and copy and overwrite the Magento root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Composer has the `--with-dependencies` flag which should resolve this for you. So the order of commands would be:

`$ composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.1.14 --no-update`

Then

`$ composer update magento/product-community-edition --with-dependencies`

**EDIT:**

**WARNING:** Before trying the below, please make a backup.

You could *try* replacing your `composer.json` file with the one below (which is one I just grabbed from a blank install on my env), then require any of the third party modules you needed using composer.

```
{
    "name": "magento/project-community-edition",
    "description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Community Edition)",
    "type": "project",
    "version": "2.1.14",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "require": {
        "magento/product-community-edition": "2.1.14",
        "composer/composer": "@alpha"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.2.0",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "3.2.2",
        "phpmd/phpmd": "@stable",
        "pdepend/pdepend": "2.5.2",
        "friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer": "~2.2.1",
        "lusitanian/oauth": "~0.8.10",
        "sebastian/phpcpd": "2.0.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Framework\\": "lib/internal/Magento/Framework/",
            "Magento\\Setup\\": "setup/src/Magento/Setup/",
            "Magento\\": "app/code/Magento/"
        },
        "psr-0": {
            "": [
                "app/code/"
            ]
        },
        "files": [
            "app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php"
        ],
        "exclude-from-classmap": [
            "**/dev/**",
            "**/update/**",
            "**/Test/**"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Magento\\Sniffs\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/Sniffs/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\": "dev/tools/Magento/Tools/",
            "Magento\\Tools\\Sanity\\": "dev/build/publication/sanity/Magento/Tools/Sanity/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Inspection\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Inspection/",
            "Magento\\TestFramework\\Utility\\": "dev/tests/static/framework/Magento/TestFramework/Utility/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    ],
    "extra": {
        "magento-force": "override"
    }
}
```

Then in a bash terminal run `$ rm -rf vendor/ composer.lock` then run `$ composer install` and then `$ composer update magento/product-community-edition --with-dependencies`

With this method you might end up with an autoload error, that may just be because you have some core modules loaded into app/. You would need to run in a bash terminal `$ rm -rf app/code/Magento/* && rm -rf app/design/frontend/Magento/* && rm -rf app/design/adminhtml/Magento/*`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. With the flag --with-dependencies I get the following conflicts.

Comment: I took a good look at how I installed Magento 2.1.7 at the beginning. `$ composer create-project -s stable --prefer-dist magento/community-edition .`

Comment: So this may be complicated or impossible to upgrade the official way? What could be the best approach to tackle this problem?

Comment: @Sai I've added an extra section to my answer that might help. I can't confirm it works, so be sure to make a backup.

Comment: Yes, this is the right way to solve my problem. I have been busy with this for a long time and now it's actually possible to upgrade my installation of 2.1.4 to 2.1.14. Thanks for your useful answer.

Comment: Hi @Sai can you please tell me did you face issues during migration? I am planning to upgrade a website from 2.1.8 to 2.1.14

Comment: Hi @Kalyan Chakravarthi V, there were no issues performing the update when the composer file was sorted out.

Comment: Thanks for the update :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ composer update magento/product-community-edition --with-dependencies
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package colinmollenhour/credis (locked at 1.6, required as 1.8.2) is satisfiable by colinmollenhour/credis[1.6] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - The requested package colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract (locked at v1.2, required as 1.3.4) is satisfiable by colinmollenhour/php-redis-session-abstract[v1.2] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 3
    - Installation request for magento/magento2ce 2.1.14 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2ce[2.1.14].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.1.14 requires magento/magento2-base 2.1.14 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2-base[2.1.14].
    - don't install magento/magento2-base 2.1.14|remove magento/magento2ce 2.1.14
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.1.14 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.1.14].
```